# resignFirstResponder makes field lose focus but keyboard doesn't disappear

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I call `resignFirstResponder` for my textField, it returns YES, but the keyboard does not disappear. I tried many variations and tips, but nothing helped. 
May have an idea why this is possible?

I repeat, the method works, **the field loses focus, but the keyboard does not disappear**

I use iOS 4.3.

**UPD:**

```
if([self.securedTextView.passField isFirstResponder]){
    if([self.securedTextView.passField canResignFirstResponder]){
        [self.securedTextView.passField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

and `[self.securedTextView.passField resignFirstResponder];` returns YES, but the keyboard is still on the screen...

Comment: what part of code you need? this is relatively large project (~318 source files)

Comment: have you connected textfield in IBOutlet or you tried creating textfield programmatically ?

Comment: Try NSlogging to check if control reaches the condition.

Comment: @narayanan-ramamoorthy, IBOutlet

Comment: @Legolas, [self.securedTextView.passField resignFirstResponder]; returns YES, I set the breakpoint at this string

Comment: Is another control becoming the first responder?

Answer (score 0):

you can use UITextField delegate methods explained below..and Try using this..

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {             
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Happy Coding...